# Rewrite .htaccess for store

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a `shop.php` file in `public_html/`

Currently I have so the URL will be `shop.php?id=something`.
I want it to be `shop/something`

I know it has something to do with `.htaccess` and I have it working right now. BUT the `.htaccess` settings I did is global and for all files, this means when I write `localhost/oeuirhg`, it redirects to `shop.php`.

Anyone knows what the correct `.htaccess` settings would be like?

These are my current settings:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./shop.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^.*\.php$ shop.php [NC,L]
```